# как перетягивать div мышкой

Tags: javascript

как сделать так чтобы красный `div` при удержании левой кнопки мыши работал так а не при `mousemove`

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', e => {
  cursor.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
});
```

```css
.cursor {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: [Drag-n-drop](https://learn.javascript.ru/drag-and-drop) первая ссылка в гугле :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В грубом приближении так:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
let canDrag = false;

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', e => {
  if (!canDrag)
    return;
    
  cursor.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
});

document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', e => canDrag = false);
cursor.addEventListener( 'mousedown', e => canDrag = true);
```

```css
.cursor {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
```